# Group mysql results by category and display them into groups under each category

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a simple css menu that gets the data from a mysql table.

My idea is to have menu like this

```
    Category 1
    - link 1
    - link 2
    - link 3
    Category 2
    - link 1
    - link 2
    - ect...
```

every link has a field named "category". So I want to group and display the links in the menu per category.

I have mysql grouping like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content group by category";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

and then I have the html like this

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="category1" class="files">
         <a href="#category1">Category 1</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">link 1</li>
             <li><a href="#">link 2</li>
             <li><a href="#">link 3</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
    <li id="category2" class="files">
         <a href="#category2">Category 2</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">link 1</li>
             <li><a href="#">link 2</li>
             <li><a href="#">link 3</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

The db table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_name` text,
  `menu_name_en` text,
  `menu_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `header_name` text,
  `header_name_en` enum('MEDIA','GENERAL') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MEDIA',
  `text` longtext NOT NULL,
  `text_en` text,
  `category` enum('Category 1', 'Category 2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Category 1',
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `visible` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO content (id, menu_name, menu_name_en, menu_url, header_name, header_name_en, text, text_en, category, date, visible) VALUES (26, 'test name', '', 'test_url', 'test name', '', '<p>test text</p>', '<p>text text</p>', 'MEDIA', '2014-02-23', '1');
```

So, I am having troubles putting the results in the loop and creating the html by category.

I read many posts here with similar content but couldn't achieve the result I wanted.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should paste a screenshot of how your content table looks like (to know how you store the links)

Comment: I am creating the links dynamically... like... index.php?link=$menu_url

Comment: I understand that, can you paste some sample data from your table?

Comment: sure: INSERT INTO `content` (`id`, `menu_name`, `menu_name_en`, `menu_url`, `header_name`, `header_name_en`, `text`, `text_en`, `category`, `date`, `visible`) VALUES (26, 'test name', '', 'test_url', 'test name', '', '<p>test text</p>', '<p>text text</p>', 'MEDIA', '2014-02-23', '1');

Comment: What does the grouping do? And update your question with any new code.

Comment: @largan You already know that the mysql_ functions are obsolete? You should use mysqli_ or PDO instead.

Answer (score 7):

I would use `ORDER BY category` instead. You can then iterate the result set like

```
$old = null;
foreach ($st as $s) {
  if $old != $s['id']
    echo 'Main category';
    $old = $s['id'];
  echo 'subcategory'
```

## Update

There exist three possible solutions until now in this thread to the problem itself.

### Original option 1

```
SELECT * FROM content group by category
foreach
  SELECT * FROM content WHERE category=$cat['category']
```

If one does only want to get each parent category once, one should use `DISTINCT` instead. One should not use `GROUP BY` without using any aggregation function. Combining `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *` is limited to (mostly) MySQL. You cannot select arbitrary columns in this case in ASNI SQL.

### A variant of option 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM content ORDER BY category
foreach
  SELECT * FROM content WHERE category=$cat['category']
```

This is the corrected version with `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`.

It still lacks of nested query calls. For 5 parent categories, this leads to 5 queries in the loop. For 10 parent categories, there are already 10 queries inside. One should avoid this kind of growing in general.

### Option 3

```
SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY category, menu_name
```

usable with the code above.

This is preferable to the other options shown due to different reasons:

- You only need one single database query to gather all data at once. The database spends (on easy queries) most of its time parsing the SQL statement one provided and only a fraction of time to actually gather the data you requested. If you provide lots of SQL code, it has to spend a lot of time parsing it. If you provide less code, it has less to do.
- It is easier for a database to get the data once, sort it once and return it to you once, instead of gather a part, sort a part, return a part and start all over again.

### still unstated option 4

There exists an until now unstated further solution. One can use prepared statements, prepare the SQL **once** and run it with different ids. This would still query all categories inside the loop, but would avoid the necessity to parse SQL code every time.

Actually I do not know if this is better or worse (or sth. in between) than my solution.

Comment: @mickmackusa I do not see me recommending that. Especially, I have written only at option 3 that "this is preferable to the other options".

Comment: In 2014, you wrote "_You should not use nested approaches for the sake of the database. Always avoid queries in loops, if this is possible. And it is easily possible in this case._" as a comment on another answer, so I was surprised that your answer provided nested queries.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, my answer should show the dis-/advantages of the different approaches, but considering these it should become clear that I prefer solution 3 (or 4).

Answer (score 6):

SQL `GROUP BY` statement groups the results so that only one row is returned for each category. This is typically used in conjunction with an aggregate function like count(), to count how many items are in each category.
What you need is an either `ORDER BY` as GhostGambler said, or a separate query for each category as shown bellow. However as you only seem to have 2 categories, this approach seems unnecessarily complicated.

```
 $q=$db->query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM content ORDER BY category");
 foreach($q as $cat){
    echo '<li id="'.$cat['category'].'" class="files">';  
    echo '<a href="'.$cat['category'].'">'.$cat['category'].'</a>'; 
    echo '<ul class="sub-menu">';
    $linkq=$db->query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE category='" . $cat['category'] . "'"); 
    foreach($linkq as $link){
       echo '<li><a href="#">'.$link['menu_name'].'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
 }
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to use this suggestion...Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/media/public_html/index.php on line 32

Comment: @largan My code uses mysqli, as the mysql extension is deprecated and should no longer be used. You can initiate it using `$db=new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database)`. You can read more on mysqli [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php). If you for some reason cannot use mysqli, you can rewrite the code by changing $db->query to query and foreach cycles to iterate over rows returned by mysql.

Comment: ok, now it doesnt show the error but it doesn't populate anything... do you think that the problem might be because my categories are in cyrillic ?

Comment: ohhh, when I look in the source it gives another error now... <li id="" class="files"><a href=""></a><ul class="sub-menu"><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/media/public_html/index.php</b> on line <b>44</b>

Comment: also I have noticed that the mysqli works as it created 5 menu rows which is the exact number of different categories in the db

Comment: I have not adjusted the second query for your table structure, my apologies. I'll edit my answer, changing `link` in the query to `*`, so you can use any column when creating the menu.

Comment: You should not use nested approaches for the sake of the database. Always avoid queries in loops, if this is possible. And it is easily possible in this case.

Comment: You save my Day :)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE group by category";
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content group by category";
```

Also since mysql is deprecated avoid using it. Use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: indeed the query is wrong, but it is a typo... in my real case is without the WHERE...

Comment: description of content table might help

Comment: just added the table structure in the main post

Comment: If one does only want to get each parent category once, one should use `DISTINCT` instead. One should not use `GROUP BY` without using any aggregation function. Combining `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *` is limited to (mostly) MySQL. You cannot select arbitrary columns in this case in ASNI SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are wondering to add sub-menu dynamically. If so then first create a 2nd table for sub-menu and add relationship between menu and sub-menu tables.

```
$select=$connection->query("select * from menus");
    while($result=$select->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<li>";        
    echo "<a href=\"#\">".$result['MenuTitle']."</a>";
    $menuid=$result['MenuId'];
    if($result==true){
    $selectsubmenu=$connection->query("Select * from submenu where menuid='$menuid'");
        echo "<ul>";
            while($resultsubmenu=$selectsubmenu->fetch_assoc()){     
                    echo "<li><a href=\"Services.php?submenu=".$resultsubmenu['SubMenuId']."\">".$resultsubmenu['SubMenuTitle']."
                    </a></li>";
                    }
        echo "</ul>";
                }
            echo "</li>";   
}
```

Comment: Iterated queries would be poor advice.