# PHP loop, separate results dependent on group_id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP loop going through my Media table, in the table they are these fields:
id (unique id_, post_id (Random id per post), user_id, file_format, group_id

If a group of multiple images are uploaded, they have a unique post_id, and have the same group_id, to distinguish between other groups of photos. However I can't figure out how to separate those groups inside the loop with an if statement to break up the div row.
Here is my code:

```html
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM media WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  ?>
  
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):?>
   <?php $group_id = $row['group_id'] ?>
  <?php if($row['group_id'] == $group_id):?>
   <div class="card-group" style="color:black;">
     <div class="card">
       <img class="card-img-top" src="uploads/<?=$row['post_id']?>.<?=$row['file_format']?>" alt="Card image cap">
       <div class="card-body">
         <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
         <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
         <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  <?php endif;?>
  <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: in each loop iteration, save the current group in a variable. That way you can test in the next iteration if it has changed or not and act acordingly.

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example of how to do so?

Comment: Can you show the query you're using as well (good to know if you're ordering by `group_id`)

Comment: I'll add it to the post, one seccond

Comment: @apokryfos Added it to the post :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967276/group-mysql-results-by-category-and-display-them-into-groups-under-each-category is very similar to this but in short you first need to `ORDER BY group_id` and then keep track of the current group_id

Comment: Thank you, I followed the post, and I have it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'am assuming you table `media` is like this:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|unique_id| post_id     | user_id   |file_format|group_id |
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|1        |56           | johndoe66 |.jpg       |Home     |
+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|2        |57           | johndoe66 |.png       |School   |  
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

So first get `SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM media WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']`

```
$conn = new mysqli("server","user","pass","your_database_name");
//will use the Object Oriented way, i'm used to it
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM media WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']`";

$groups_result = $conn->query($sql);
//create a group array and format it as you like
$user_groups = array();
while($row = $groups_result->fetch_array()){
   $user_groups[] = $row['group_id`];
}
```

That will first get all the distinct groups for that user and store them in `$user_groups`. Then:

Foreach `$user_groups`:

You now want to get the posts for each group:

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($user_groups);$i++){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM media WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND group_id = '".$user_groups[$i]."'"
  //create a group div with maybe the <div id='$user_groups[$i]'>
   while($row = $mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query($sql)){
      //create a picture collage of all the posts in the current $i group
   }
  //close the group </div>
}
```

Does the edit help?.

Comment: Would you mind adding the first part of your answer into the code, Just trying to under stand it a little better. I can see where your going though :)

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Great explanation too. Thank you :)

Comment: Dont forget to give the thumbs up. And confirm that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to get something similar? I used a temporary variable to determine when the group changes during the loop, and I ordered your mysql query by group_id:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM media WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user']."' order by group_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$oldGroupId = -1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $group_id = $row['group_id'];
    if($oldGroupId != $group_id) {
        if($oldGroupId != -1) {
            echo("</div>");
        }
        echo("<div class=\"card-group\" style=\"color:black;\">\n");
        $oldGroupId = $group_id;
    }
    echo("<div class=\"card\">
            <img class=\"card-img-top\" src=\"uploads/<?=".($row['post_id'])."?>.<?=".($row['file_format'])."?>\" alt=\"Card image cap\">
            <div class=\"card-body\">
              <h4 class=\"card-title\">Card title</h4>
              <p class=\"card-text\">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class=\"card-text\"><small class=\"text-muted\">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>");
}
echo("</div>\n");
```