# how to print table with their foreign keys

Tags: php

I have two tables, with foreign key ID on people table:

school:

```
| Schools | School_id |
|---------|-----------|
| One     | 1         |
| Two     | 2         |
| Three   | 3         |
| Four    | 4         |
```

people:

```
| Name | ID |
|------|----|
| John | 3  |
| Paul | 2  |
| Van  | 1  |
| Mara | 2  |
```

What output I seek:

```
(SCHOOL) ONE
  VAN 
(SCHOOL) TWO
  PAUL 
  MARA
(SCHOOL) THREE 
  JOHN
(SCHOOL) FOUR
  no elements
```

I have sql query to fetch data from these tables:

```html
$sql = "SELECT `people`.`vardas`,
                `school`.`pavadinimas`
                 FROM `{$this->school}`
        INNER JOIN `{$this->people}`
        ON `{$this->people}`.`ID` = `{$this->school}`.`school_id`
        ORDER BY `{$this->school}`.`school`";
```

But i dont know how to print it like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group mysql results by category and display them into groups under each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967276/group-mysql-results-by-category-and-display-them-into-groups-under-each-category)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `INNER JOIN` to make link with tables

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        Schools , 
        Name 
          FROM School 
          INNER JOIN people p ON school.School_id=p.ID 
          WHERE School_id=p.ID 
          ORDER BY School_id";
```

Output

```
+---------+------+
| Schools | Name |
+---------+------+
| one     | van  |
| two     | mara |
| two     | paul |
| three   | john |
+---------+------+
```